# Sending Class object as messages to Azure Queue Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage-queues

I'm working on a c# console project to send a class object as a message to the Azure queue.

```
public class Myclass
{
public string? Userid { get; set; }

}

class Program
{
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string connectionString = "<string>";
    string queueName = "<queuename>";

    QueueClientOptions options = new QueueClientOptions();
    options.Diagnostics.IsLoggingEnabled = false;

    QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName, options);

    var message = new Myclass
    {
        Userid = "kth12",        
    };
    string jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);

    try
    {
        await queueClient.SendMessageAsync(jsonMessage);
        Console.WriteLine("Message sent");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send the message. Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
}
```

This is the code I used. But my question is why should I serialize the class object to send it as a message to Azure Queue? Can't I send it without serialization? or is there any particular reason for serializing and deserializing?

Is there any way to pass it without serialization?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> You need to serialize your class object before sending a message to Azure storage.

Azure Queue Storage is a just a message queuing service that stores messages as a sequence of bytes. And it does not understand `complex object types` , so [serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messages-payloads) is required.

- Serialization is the process of converting an object into a format (such as JSON) that can be easily transmitted and converted into an object.
- When you send a message to Azure Queue Storage, you need to provide a string representation of the message content. In your case, you are using `JSON serialization` to convert `Myclass object` into a `string (jsonMessage)`. This allows you to send the serialized object as a message payload.

And to convert it back into an object, you will need to deserialize the string back into your class object.

Hence, `serialization and deserialization` are necessary when sending and receiving objects through Azure Queue Storage.

```
private static async Task SendMessage(string namespaceName)
        {
            var connectionString = $"ConnectionString";
            var qc = new QueueClient(connectionString, "myqueue11");

            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test message"));
            await qc.SendAsync(message);

            Console.WriteLine("Message sent successfully.");
        }
```

[image]

Message sent to Queue.

[image]

For more information, refer to the [blog](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/deal-with-azure-service-bus-message-size) and Message [encode.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/message-encode)